# deleting files with .mp3 extension in android

Tags: android

how do i delete all files having .jpg extension from my sd card? i can display all jpg files in a list but dont know how to delete. i am new to android, please bear with my question if possible.

```
view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    //getting SDcard root path
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    getfile(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        view.addView(textView);
    }

}

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `File.delete()` ?

Comment: i have solved it . can you tell me what storage is getExternalStorageDirectory()? internal rom or ext sd card?